# how to add types to "file types managed" in firefox?

Tags: firefox

When I click link to log file(I have a log of links like that) the firefox opens the file, but I want to just save it(like I do with PDFs). However I dont have log file defined as [Manage File Type](http://www.watchingthenet.com/how-to-configure-firefox-to-open-different-types-of-files.html). How can I add log files there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox, like all other browsers, uses the HTTP **`Content-Type`** header to decide how to handle the page. In your case, the log file is served as **`text/plain`**, which is handled by Firefox internally. Whether the URL ends in `.txt` or `.log` does not matter.

If you have access to the web server, you could reconfigure it to serve `.log` files as, for example, `application/x-log-file` - either by [editing `.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) if the server is running Apache, or by reconfiguring the server itself.

---

If you don't have access to the web server's configuration, it's also possible to write a small script (in PHP or any other language) that would set headers and output the desired file:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["file"])) {
    header("Content-Type: application/x-log-file");
    readfile(basename($_GET["file"]));
} else {
    echo "<ul>\n";
    foreach (glob("*.log") as $name) {
        echo '<li> <a href="?file='.htmlspecialchars($name).'">'
            .htmlspecialchars($name)."</a>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>\n";
}
```

Comment: cool idea, however If I make page like this <a href="bla.pdf">a</a> and click it the firefox saves the pdf to the file. he recognize the extension. I think there should be a way in adv ff options to add new recognizable types.

Comment: @01: It doesn't. Your webserver tells it that the file is of type `application/pdf`. [See for yourself.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829/)

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work with `.rdp` files with the following links:

- [Associate an Action with a File Type in FireFox](https://superuser.com/questions/46017/how-do-you-associate-an-action-with-a-file-type-in-firefox-3-0)
- [Mozilla Mime Types](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf)