# Tell firefox to use Flash player instead of download for mp4 files

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Installation order:

1. Firefox
2. Flash Player
3. VLC with firefox addon (for playback)

Before step 2, mp4 files were being displayed in firefox (like youTube etc).

After step 3, I noticed that `mp4` videos are playing using vlc (in browser). I disabled tha vlc plugin and now firefox is asking what to do with the file (the download menu appears).

In the Options->Applications I see the following. There is no option such as `Use Flash player (in Firefox)` like the adobe acrobat plugin.

I tried installing flash player again but with no luck. Is there a way to fix this without ruining this Firefox profile?

I am refering to `mp4` and firefox because using chrome and right-clicking on video I see the flash player context menu, and in firefox by clicking the video (that is just blank, without the player) I am getting the download dialog.

Environment: Win7 x64, Firefox 15

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you associate an action with a file type in Firefox 3.0?](http://superuser.com/questions/46017/how-do-you-associate-an-action-with-a-file-type-in-firefox-3-0)